# Verify why a process went down accidentally on Solaris 11

Tags: process, solaris, troubleshooting

I want to know what reasons could have caused a process to be killed automatically by a system or taken down. What file do I need to verify, or how do I know why the process crashes accidentally?

Is there a file that I can check for a short description of a downed process, or something like that?

Comment: run as root `dmesg` or check `/var/adm/messages` your application's log might give some clues. Be aware that diagostic are seldom written in human form.

Comment: See my coment below about it. The application does not show me anything about these issue of process down automatically without any reason.

Comment: add more to the post, free/used RAM, applications, what does the server do, if the server is in the Internet. If I had to make a wild guess I would go with memory exhaustion.

Comment: No. Is an own server with private apps developed inside, so, it is not on Internet. Server actually are running Solaris 10 and 11 on sparc architecture. Servers have more than 50GB of RAM and we have M-4000 and M-5000 Oracle Servers.

Comment: If your apps are developed in-house, the developers, or the people original developers handed the support to, should know something about the application(s) Unless you get help from the development team or the vendor, it is going to be a very painful troubleshooting process, especially considering application doesn't generate any logs. Very poorly written app in my opinion.

Comment: The thing is, the application doesn't show me any log info file after or at the same time that the application ran. But, the app saves an history of logs and the thing is it seems that the properly os killed it by any reason the application process, with out the possibility to see in the same time that the application process were killed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the application logs (if available). Then check the system logs (ie. `/var/adm/messages`, `/var/cron/log` if launched by cron, `/var/svc/log/` in case of service etc.). If the process is maintained by SMF, check `svcs -xv` and appropriate logs.

Also have a look if `coreadm` is configured to create core dumps for crashing processes. Note that core dumps are probably not created when a process is killed and terminates normally.

Comment: I had a issue, lastnight at 3:25 am without any reason many process down automatically and viewing the log files (**system logs, dmesg, svcs -xv**, etc) I didn't find anything because the last log inside these files was at 3:10 am (ten minutes before the problem).

Any idea?.

Comment: Did you check the console logs from the XSCF? Did you check for scheduled tasks and/or possible audited events? Check `praudit -l /var/audit/XXX` where XXX is the file with timestamp appropriate to your event, probably the last or second last file.

Comment: Actually we have the auditing disable.